# "inferior" process in clojure - redirecting asyncronous output for further processing

Tags: shell, clojure, future

I'd like to maintain a long-running interactive shell process inside Clojure -- what would be called an "inferior" process in Emacs.  I assume the basic idea is plenty familiar because Clojure itself can run inside of Emacs via CIDER.  I'd be happy to know if there are any working examples of this set-up using Clojure as the top-level process.

*Edit: I found this "[shell](https://gist.github.com/spieden/482a6c3a8bd3b0f82c89)" Gist, which is a very nice looking wrapper for [Conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch) which gives me some food for thought.*

With my own [first attempt with Conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch/issues/32): I wasn't able to feed strings into `python` and get output back the same way that I can with, e.g., `cat`.  But with a bit of experimentation I figured out the basics and got around the first roadblocks.

```clj
(require '[me.raynes.conch.low-level :as sh])
(def sh-python (sh/proc "python" "-i"))      ; "-i" needed to get interactive mode
#'flowrweb.core/sh-python
(future (sh/stream-to-out sh-python :out))   
#future[{:status :pending, :val nil} 0x516f3fff]
(sh/feed-from-string sh-python "1+1\n")      ; just returns nil on the CIDER repl
2                                            ; <- but we see "2" with the lein repl 
nil
```

So I know the data I'm interested in is available, although it is a bit strange that it doesn't print in CIDER (**sub-question**... why isn't the 2 printed?).  Anyway, for my use case, I don't need it *printed*; rather I just want to get it back as a string.

#### First attempt:

```clj
(def pyout (future (sh/stream-to-string sh-python :out)))
;=> #'flowrweb.core/py-out
(sh/feed-from-string sh-python "1+2\n")
;=> 3
;=> nil
@pyout
^C                     ; <- the process hangs
```

It seems that `sh/stream-to-string` isn't quite doing what I need.

#### How about doing it with `with-out-str`?

```clj
(def something (with-out-str (sh/feed-from-string sh-python "1+3\n")))
;=> 4
;=> #'user/something
something
;=> ""                 ;<- where is the "4"?
```

Nope, that didn't work either.

**tl;dr**: How can I redirect the output from a Conch subprocess for future processing?

Comment: Now that I've read more about futures I can see that the "first attempt" is a bit silly.  The future won't have completed, which is why the process hangs.  Not sure what's wrong with `with-out-str` attempt though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enough to get started with.

```clj
(require '[me.raynes.conch.low-level :as sh])
;=> nil
(def my-stringwriter (java.io.StringWriter.))
;=> #'user/my-stringwriter
(def sh-python (sh/proc "python" "-i"))
;=> #'user/sh-python
(future (sh/stream-to sh-python :out my-stringwriter)) ; NOT redirecting *out* 
;=> #future[{:status :pending, :val nil} 0x4358e46d]
(sh/feed-from-string sh-python "1+1\n")
;=> nil
(.toString my-stringwriter)
;=> "2\n"
(sh/feed-from-string sh-python "1+2\n")
;=> nil
(.toString my-stringwriter)
;=> "2\n3\n"
```

Keeping in mind that "The agent system supports sharing changing state between threads in an asynchronous and independent manner" ([clojure.org docs](http://clojure.org/about/concurrent_programming)), I think that a sensible way to encapsulate this is:

```clj
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def a-stringwriter (agent (java.io.StringWriter.)))
(future (sh/stream-to sh-python :out @a-stringwriter))

(defn feed-python [user-input]
  (future (sh/feed-from-string sh-python (str user-input "\n"))
          (Thread/sleep 1000)
          (str/split (.toString @a-stringwriter) #"\n")))
```

Then you can write e.g. `@(feed-python "10+20")` to send and receive results from python.  This command will show the history of previous interactions as well as the latest one.  For most use cases only the latest addition is relevant.

```clj
(defn gljcon [user-input]
  (last @(feed-python user-input)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no Clojure specific machinery for managing processes. Also, OS processes fall out of the strictly-speaking Clojure focus, as it's a hosted language and process management is definitely something the host should manage (e.g. the JVM or CLR).

So, let's say you're running Clojure on the JVM. One facility that the JVM exposes to create subprocesses is the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), which you could invoke from your Clojure code just like the following ([credits go to @codification](https://gist.github.com/codification/1984857)):

```
(ns proc
  (:import [java.lang ProcessBuilder])
  (:use [clojure.java.io :only [reader writer]]))

(defn spawn [& args]
  (let [process (-> (ProcessBuilder. args)
                  (.start))]
    {:out (-> process
            (.getInputStream)
            (reader))
     :err (-> process
            (.getErrorStream)
            (reader))
     :in (-> process
           (.getOutputStream)
           (writer))
     :process process}))
```

Comment: Conch provides a wrapper at this level (`sh/proc` [in their examples](https://github.com/Raynes/conch#low-level-usage)).  What I'm seeing is that `python` and `cat` behave differently -- if I feed `1+1\n` to `cat`, I get back `1+1`.  But if I feed it to `python` I get nothing (whereas I'd expect to get `2`).

Comment: I can now get output from python to print, but need to figure out how to access it for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the InputStream returned by sh/proc, open it with reader, then use line-seq to create a lazy sequence of output lines. This should be run on another thread as doseq will block until output is available.

```
(let [{out-stream :out} (sh/proc "ls" "-l")]
  (with-open [out-rdr (clojure.java.io/reader out-stream)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq out-rdr)]
      ; do something with line: Like feed it into core.async chan
      ; (>!! some-chan line)
      ; or pass it to some fn
      (println line))))
```